# $group by and select other fields not in group by condition

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create a query of mongoDB
--> find document on the basis of key('field1'+'field2')
--> select other fields of the query also
by using group condition I am getting the field only that are present in $group identifier.

`db.customer.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":{"field1":"$field1","lfield2":"$field2"},
}},
}])`

I am a beginner and according to sql we can only select field that are in group condition.

Is there any way to select other field in group by?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can select *other* fields that are not specified in the group `_id`. Read [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) to understand better. In order to select *other* fields, you need to use one of [these](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/#group-accumulator-operators) accumulator operators in the `$group` stage.

For example,

```
db.customer.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":{"field1":"$field1","lfield2":"$field2"},
         "otherField1":{$push:"$otherField1"}}}
])
```